# Can't upload image to server because of 500 server error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Been trying to upload an image to a nodejs server. Stumped by this 500 error.

This is what the react component's onclick handler looks like :

```
  onClickHandler = () => {
    const data = new FormData() 
    for(var x = 0; x<this.state.selectedFile.length; x++) {
      data.append('file', this.state.selectedFile[x])
    }
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/upload", data, { //originally 8000
      onUploadProgress: ProgressEvent => {
        this.setState({
          loaded: (ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total*100),
        })
      },
    })
      .then(res => { // then print response status
        toast.success('upload success')
      })
      .catch(err => { // then print response status
        toast.error('upload fail')
      })
    }
```

And this is what the relevant parts of the server.js looks like:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './public')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' +file.originalname )
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('file');

app.post('/upload',function(req, res) {

  upload(req, res, function (err) {

      if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
          return res.status(500).json(err)
        // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
      } else if (err) {
          return res.status(500).json(err)
        // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
      } 

      return res.status(200).send(req.file)
      // Everything went fine.
    })
});
```

I think the problem is arising from my somehow having configured the post request incorrectly but I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Or perhaps it's because I've set it to the wrong port?

Comment: You are returning an error to the client, can you tell us what that specific error is? Alternatively, you can console.log the err on the server side

Comment: @Saddy The error message in console is :POST http://localhost:8080/upload 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: A `500` error is very ambigious, that just means that something on the server is erroring. Does `console.log(err)` on the server only give that?

Comment: I've changed the port to 8080 since the server is listening on port 8080

Comment: @Saddy I'm currently running the server.js on localhost. Where am I supposed to insert the console.log(err)? I put it in the upload var in server.js but it's not logging

Comment: I think it is erroring out under the upload function. Place it one line before both `return res.status(500).json(err)`

Comment: Is that error because I need to somehow create/give permissions for that directory in my files?

Comment: Your problem is most likely due to the folder not existing. Does the public folder exist?

Comment: @Saddy Thank you very much! The problem has been fixed. Couldn't have done it without your help. You saved me hours on this thing. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! To help others, please accept my answer submitted below. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely due to the folder not existing. Please try to create the ./public  folder (D:\Projects\mango_finance\react-fin\src\server\public). [Source](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/513)